# findViewByID return null only on some Samsung Android Nougat devices

Tags: android, titlebar, android-7.0-nougat

I've Activity with a custom titlebar loaded like this

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
            final RelativeLayout frameLayout =  new RelativeLayout(this);

            setContentView(frameLayout);
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                    R.layout.lfpdftitlebar_v2);

            View v = findViewById(R.id.pdftoolbar);
            //v is Null only on some Android 7 devices


}
```

and the R.id.pdftoolbar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pdftoolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pdftoolbar_all"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@color/light_blue"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Only on some Android 7 devices I can't access View defined in layout R.layout.window_title because the this.findViewById or getWindow().findViewById() on this object return **null**

Comment: Where is `findViewById()`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: All code is in OnCreate of the activity

Comment: Code speaks louder than words. Please show a **complete** code example which anyone can compile. Also provide the full error message which you receive.